# How to Unwrap A Circle Into A Strip

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv

I am wanting to create a UV map that will cause my texture to stretch to my favor.  **I want to unwrap a circle so that it's a rectangular strip.**

If I can unwrap it into a rectangular strip, I can make a texture by drawing some straight lines.  Then, I think when I apply the texture onto the object, it will result with the lines being stretched and following the curve of the circle mesh.
How can I unwrap the circle this way?

Comment: What do you mean by "to my favor"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you keep an edge loop close to the center you can easily do what you want with an *Unwrap > Follow Active Quad* (you just need to select the whole ring then shift select a last face at the end to make it active). Then unwrap the center and place it wherever you want on your texture.

[image]
[image]

Comment: and your central circle can be as small as you want  ;)