# How do you use texture to be spiraled or circular?

Tags: texturing

If I add texture of just a horizontal or vertical pattern, then how do I manipulate it to be circular, like the top of toilet paper?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Are you talking about a procedural texture or an image texture?

Comment: Image texture. I'm trying to make a roll of yarn, and the image texture i've dropped into the shader editor is fine, but the top needs to be circular, and not stretching straight across.

Comment: maybe this will answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189572/how-to-unwrap-a-circle-into-a-strip/189575#189575

Comment: I thought about trying to select the top material of the roll of yarn, and assign a new material and apply the wave texture, but not sure how to use it correctly - or if that's the best option.

Comment: That doesn't look like what I need. If i'm read it correctly that's showing how to make a circular pattern into a straight rectangular pattern. I almost need to do the opposite.

Comment: no, that's showing how to use an horizontal or vertical texture pattern to make it circular

Comment: Ok that did not work for me. Thanks anyway. I’ll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: why didn't it work? Maybe edit your question to give some additional details

Comment: i rebuilt the cylinder without modeling it at all and it sort of worked, but just gave a spiraled effect. I want more of a wrapped circle effect/appearance since it's supposed to look like this is a ball of yarn